# how to extract data from column which looks like a dictionary in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi I am new to `pandas`/`python` and trying to read a txt file in `pandas`
I want to extract `key`, `value` pairs for each row.
Make the `key` as new column name and its respective `value` as values.

**Input**

```
data   
{'Name': 'Tim', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'} 
{'Name': 'Tom', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'}
{'Name': 'Jim', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'}
{'Name': 'John', 'Class': 'Ninth'}
```

**Expected Output**:

```
Name    Class   Hobbies
Tim Ninth   Football
Tom Ninth   Football
Jim Ninth   Football
John    Ninth   NA
```

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('9data.txt',sep = '\t')
df1['Name'] = df1['data'].apply(lambda x : x.values()[1])
print(df1)
```

**Error**: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Is there any way in which i can do this in `pandas` ?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df1['data'].tolist())`?

Comment: @Anurag Dabas - that should work, but the way this data is presented there seems to be spaces at the end of the row causing it to be a string. Maybe it's how it's pasted in but if your formula works, great. otherwise below works.

Answer (score 1):

The way the data was being read, I could get it a new dataframe using `eval()`. This will iterate over each cell creating a new dataframe then concatenating them.

```
data='''data
{'Name': 'Tim', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'} 
{'Name': 'Tom', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'}
{'Name': 'Jim', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'}
{'Name': 'John', 'Class': 'Ninth'}'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\t', engine='python')
df1 = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(eval(x)) for x in df['data']])
```

Output

```
   Name  Class   Hobbies
0   Tim  Ninth  Football
0   Tom  Ninth  Football
0   Jim  Ninth  Football
0  John  Ninth       NaN
```

If you can get your data look like this, this is simpler method that Anurag Dabas alludes to. You might consider reading the file into a list first, then creating the dataframe, rather creating a dataframe from a dataframe.

```
datal = [{'Name': 'Tim', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'},
{'Name': 'Tom', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'},
{'Name': 'Jim', 'Class': 'Ninth', 'Hobbies' : 'Football'},
{'Name': 'John', 'Class': 'Ninth'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(datal)
df
```

Comment: (+1) To combine both ideas, you can use `data_list = [eval(line) for line in io.StringIO(data)]` and then `df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)`